# Running Typescript script with ts-node fails to import non src module from node library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, three.js

I have a script that, given some input, uses the [three.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three) library to apply geometric transformations to some input data. I run this script using `ts-node pipeline.ts`.  My project is structured as follows:

```bash
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── pipeline.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

I am able to import classes from this library's src, e.g.,

```js
const { CatmullRomCurve3, MathUtils, Vector3, Vector4 } = require('three');
```

However, when I try to import a class NURBSCurve (with `const { NURBSCurve } = require('three');`) that's located in a different set of modules (`examples` instead of `src`) The line `let curve = new NURBSCurve(...)` raises a `TypeError: NURBSCurve is not a constructor`

I've tried some variants with `import` as well:

- `import {NURBSCurve} from 'three'` results in `error TS2305: Module '"three"' has no exported member 'NURBSCurve'.`
- `import { NURBSCurve } from 'three/examples/jsm/curves/NURBSCurve';` results in `Error: Cannot find module '.../project/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/curves/NURBSCurve'`
- `import { NURBSCurve } from 'three/examples/jsm/curves/NURBSCurve.js'` results in

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module .../project/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/curves/NURBSCurve.js from .../project/src/pipeline.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of NURBSCurve.js in .../project/src/pipeline.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I've tried installing the types libraries for node and three with

```bash
npm install --save @types/three
npm install --save @types/node
```

to no avail.

@types/three generates a .d.ts NURBSCurve.d.ts, which is what VS Code's intellisense correctly finds as NURBSCurve's definition, but this doesn't seem to be the case with `ts-node`.

For completion's sake, my tsconfig.json is configured as follows, adjacent to similar projects to mine I've seen on the web:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

EDIT:  It seems like the ts executable I'm using `ts-node` is the problem (what config am I missing?).

**running my script with `npx tsx` works.**

I've rephrased my question for `ts-node` and going to leave this open for the community.

Answer (score 2):

I installed a typescript boilerplate from https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-typescript-boilerplate and was able to successfully import `NURBSCurve` after `npm i three` with:

```
import { Vector2 } from 'three';
import { NURBSCurve } from 'three/examples/jsm/Addons.js';

function func(): void {
  const curve = new NURBSCurve(2, [2, 3], [new Vector2(2, 3)])
  console.log(curve);
}

func();
```

I built and ran the code, and I was able to print this successfully without errors:

```js
NURBSCurve {
  type: 'Curve',
  arcLengthDivisions: 200,
  degree: 2,
  knots: [ 2, 3 ],
  controlPoints: [ Vector4 { x: 2, y: 3, z: 0, w: 1 } ],
  startKnot: 0,
  endKnot: 1
}
```

So maybe try `import { NURBSCurve } from 'three/examples/jsm/Addons.js';` ?

Comment: I am curious how you ran your script?  Using `ts-node` runs into several errors, including `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`, but using `npx tsx` works. While I have a functioning program now, I'd still like to know why `ts-node` doesn't work so I've edited the question for specificity.

Comment: I used `tsc -p tsconfig.json` to build the project, and plain `node build/src/main.js` to run the javascript compiled by `tsc`. `tsc` is the official CLI command for compiling typescript to javascript. `ts-node` is a NPM package that allows you to run typescript without precompiling. It is a tool that may require additional configuration to make it work properly in your project. Perhaps it's worth checking out https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node for specifics.